# Изи задачка по Javascript на метод reduce

Tags: javascript, методы

Дан вот такой многомерный массив: [['good', 'bAd', 'bad'],
['bad', 'bAd', 'bad', 'bad'], ['good', 'bAd', 'bad']]. Мне нужно вывести фразы, если в нем встречается 1 good, больше 2-ух good или если они отсутствуют.

Вот мое решение:

```js
    let well = (x) => x.flat(Infinity).reduce(el => {
      if (typeof(el) === 'string' && (el === 'good') === 1) {
        return 'Publish!';
      } else if (typeof(el) === 'string' && (el === ' good') > 2) {
        return 'I smell a series!';
      } else {
        return 'Fail';
      }
    })
    
    console.log(well([['good', 'bAd', 'bad'], 
    ['bad', 'bAd', 'bad', 'bad'], ['good', 'bAd', 'bad']]));
```

Но оно не работает. Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Я хочу решить именно этим способом, так как учусь работать с методами map, filter и reduce.

Comment: `(el === 'good') === 1` - это что делает? И зачем здесь `typeof(el) === 'string'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> что я делаю не так?

Всё. Начиная с того, что reduce вовсе не подходит для данной задачи. Скорее `filter()`

```
let well = (x) => x.flat(Infinity).reduce(el => {
  if (typeof(el) === 'string' && (el === 'good') === 1) {
    return 'Publish!';
  } else if (typeof(el) === 'string' && (el === ' good') > 2) {
    return 'I smell a series!';
  } else {
    return 'Fail';
  }
})

well([['good', 'bAd', 'bad'], 
['bad', 'bAd', 'bad', 'bad'], ['good', 'bAd', 'bad']]);
```

`x.flat(Infinity)` Сразу из входного массива получаете плоский массив элементов good / bad.

1. `.reduce(функция, начальное_значение)` — начальное не указано, поэтому берется первый элемент указанного массива, `'good'`
2. `(el === 'good') === 1` → el === 'good' возвращает только true / false. Сравнивая значение типа boolean с числом 1, всегда будете получать false (из-за оператора строгого === сравнения. Типы не совпадают - до свидания)
3. Функция внутри reduce получает четыре параметра:
   `(текущее_значение_начальной_переменной, элемент, индекс, весь_массив)`

То, что вернет эта функция - передается в качестве текущего значения (оно же, `el`) на следующую итерацию функции.

У вас после первой итерации `el` получит одно из значений Publish, I smell, Fail, и дальше будет бесполезно кругами бегать.

---

```js
let status = get_publish_status([['good', 'bAd', 'bad'], 
['bad', 'bAd', 'bad', 'bad'], ['good', 'bAd', 'bad']]);

console.log(status);

/***/
function get_publish_status(arr) {
  let good = arr.flat(100).filter(str => /good/i.test(str)).length;
  
  return ( good >= 2 ) ? ( 'I smell series!' ) : ( good == 1 ? 'Publish!' : 'Fail' );
}
```

---

P.s. Чтобы понять reduce, достаточно знать, что это одно и то же:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3]; 

/***/
let sum = 0;
arr.forEach( (el, index) => {
  sum += el;
});
console.log(sum);

/***/
let result = arr.reduce( (sum, el, index) => {
  sum += el;
  return sum;
}, 0);
console.log(result);
```

reduce просто таскает с собой лишнюю переменную, которую спокойно можно было объявить и вне перебора. Просто, компактная запись через reduce иногда удобна для мелких однострочных функций.

---

UPD: «Через reduce можно реализовать map и filter» (c) @Grundy

```js
let status = get_publish_status([['good', 'bAd', 'bad'], 
['bad', 'bAd', 'bad', 'bad'], ['good', 'bAd', 'bad']]);

console.log(status);

/***/
function get_publish_status(arr) {
  let good = arr.flat(100).reduce(myFilter, []).length;
    //  Начальное значение (goods) - пустой [] массив
  
  function myFilter(goods, word) {
    if( /good/i.test( word ) ) goods.push(word);
    return goods;
  }
  
  return ( good >= 2 ) ? ( 'I smell series!' ) : ( good == 1 ? 'Publish!' : 'Fail' );
}
```

Comment: через reduce можно реализовать map и filter

Comment: _это одно и то же:_ - только в reduce достаточно сразу вернуть sum+el, а не менять переменную

Comment: @Grundy Да, `result = arr.reduce( (sum, el) => sum + el );` тот пример для наглядности)

Comment: этот вариант намного нагляднее

Comment: спасибо большое!